# Using an option in the app ONLY during a certain time that i set

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In my (first) application I am using some kind of "Wheel of fortune".
I want it to be usable only on Fridays, and after it has been used, I want it to be unusable  until the next Friday only! and so on..

Actually, I want it to be disposable per week.

Is this possible?

Comment: What's the question? Do you ask whether that _can_ be done technically, or whether such app will be approved in the AppStore?

Comment: Consider accepting answers that are helpful, it rewards the people who take the time to answer and increases your reputation. 

Click on the hollow checkmark next to the answer that is best.  [See this page for more detail](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Also please consider and accepting past answers, doing so will increase your reputation and allow more capabilities, See [reputation faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)

Comment: You should probably involve a server in this, the user can manipulate the phone date however he wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can very simply check whether it's Friday and set a flag to allow the functionality:

```
NSCalendar * cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate * today = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents * comps = [cal components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit
                                  fromDate:today];

if( [comps weekday] == 6 ){
    todayIsFriday = YES;
}
```

I'm not too sure how this will work if the user's calendar is something other than Gregorian; the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000039-SW1) kind of leaves specifics of the individual calendars to guesswork.

Comment: Josh, Thank you, its working but now after i checked its friday, the user spined the Wheel of Fortune. now i want that after he used it once, he won't be able to use it again until next week. can you help me with this one?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Easiest way: use [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Add a NSDate object to `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` about the last time, the wheel was used.